# Como encriptar o código de carregamento do vídeo do JwPlayer

Tags: javascript, html, criptografia, reprodutor-de-video

Ola gostaria de saber como posso realizar uma encriptação no código fonte em uma área especifica do Jwplayer utilizando php ou javascript, para encobrir os dados de funcionamento do player bem como a url do arquivo do vídeo.

Dando uma busca pela internet achei um site que esta usando uma encriptação que deixa a área, onde fica os dados de funcionamento do jwplayer como mostrado no campo de código logo abaixo, essa encriptação esta aparecendo diretamente no código fonte, com o player funcionando perfeitamente.

```
<script type="text/javascript">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('47("33").32({31:"4://3.0/12/6/7/30-29.10","5":"4://28.3.0/27/26/25/24/2/23/22/19/18-16.15",13:"14%",17:"16:9",34:1,21:"36",48:"56",55:"35",53:11,8:{5:"4://3.0/12/6/7/8-52.10",51:"4://3.0",50:"11",49:"37-46",},45:{44:1,43:{42:1,41:1,40:"39://38.54.20",}}});',10,57,'biz|false||animesvision|https|file|assets|images|logo||png|true|v1|width|100|mp4||aspectratio|AnV|480p|com|startparam|Wu_Shen_Zhu_Zai|W|KVN4SX99wNZ03YklXztB|1587617611|2LOG0Dpqe7oim3XUST9SHA|assistir|forja2|banner|vision|image|setup|playersd|autostart|data|start|top|opensignal|wss|wsSignalerAddr|live|logLevel|p2pConfig|debug|hlsjsConfig|right|jwplayer|primary|position|hide|link|footer2|floating|cdnbye|preload|html5'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script>
```

Pelo que observei a encriptação e realizada no site automaticamente a cada postagem de um novo vídeo.

Gostaria de saber como posso realizar esse tipo de processo de encriptação no código mostrado abaixo.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const player = jwplayer('player').setup({
            image: jw.image,
            mute: false,
            volume: 100,
            autostart: jw.auto,
            repeat: false,
            abouttext: jw.text,
            aboutlink: jw.link,
            skin: {
                active: jw.color
            },
            logo: {
                file: jw.logo,
                hide: true,
                link: jw.link,
                margin: '15',
                position: jw.lposi
            },
            sources: 'url do vídeo',
        })
    </script>
```